# How to correctly map <tab> for <Plug>Functions() on Windows?

Tags: vimrc, gvim, microsoft-windows

I am using gVim on Windows, and have only recently run into a very problematic situation: my <kbd>Tab</kbd> key stops working in insert mode! Pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key does not give any output.

In order to use the plugin [snipmate](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim) which expands snippets by calling a function defined as `<Plug>`-function, I have to remap <kbd>ctrl+q</kbd> to achieve the functionality. However, when I map the same content to <kbd>Tab</kbd>, pressing the key is still not bringing me anything.

I checked the mappings defined for `<tab>` using two methods:

1. Using `Listmaps` plugin, by calling the command `:Listmaps`, and found that `<tab>` has been defined correctly;
2. The mapping on `<tab>` seems to be valid upon checking `:map <tab>`;

Nevertheless, <kbd>Tab</kbd> seems to have been disabled.

What I don't understand is that: how come the same syntax of mapping would bring about different results. Who should I specify the `<Plug>Func()` mappings? If this is really wired, would it be worth it to try a fresh installation?

Thank you!

The pair of mappings that I have specified:

```
imap <c-q> <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger
imap <tab> <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger
```

Comment: Is it possible that Vim is not able to detect the `Tab` key being pressed?

Comment: check `set paste?`. If the output is not  `nopaste`, turn off paste mode, the mappings should work fine then. Disable pastemode by default, and add something like `set pastetoggle=<F2>` to your vimrc file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to add `<esc>a`, especially if you are using YouCompleteMe plugin along with SnipMate.

```
imap <tab> <esc>a<Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger
```

Also verify that tab key is working by pressing `ctrl`+`i`, as it is identical to `<tab>` in Vim.

Finally, check your `.vimrc` if there is `set paste`, and remove that line if it exists or replace it with `set nopaste`.